# How to install this kind of requirements.txt file in anaconda env

Tags: python, anaconda

I have requiremnets.txt like this

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
appdirs                   1.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blis                      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
boto3                     1.11.16                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.14.16                  pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
cachetools                4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
...........
...........
```

How do I install these in a virtual conda env?

`conda install --file requirements.txt` seem to not work.

Comment: and you've created and activated the `conda` env?

Comment: What is the output on `conda install --file requirements.txt`?

Comment: CondaValueError: could not parse '_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main' in: requirements.txt

Comment: How did you get that file? Based on what I found, you'd dump `conda list -e` to pass to another conda environment

Comment: @h4z3 other's github

Comment: @Kulasangar yes

Comment: That's not a valid `requirements.txt` file. Please check the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/).

Comment: @sam5922 then report is as an issue that it's not valid requirements.txt file for conda

Comment: @accdias conda's requirements file is already different that pip's requirements.txt file, this question is specifically for conda :)

Comment: I'm a bit inclined to say that Conda follows exactly the `requirements.txt` file format from `pip` as well. But I'm not that used with Conda environment to say it for sure. Do you have any documentation reference to point us to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print $1 "==" $2}' old_requirements.txt > requirements.txt
conda create -n myenv python=3.10
conda activate myenv
pip install -r new_requirements.txt
```

It's just an example, how it can work. `awk` command will create a new file with standard format:

```
_libgcc_mutex==0.1
absl-py==0.9.0
appdirs==1.4.3
astor==0.8.1
blas==1.0
blis==0.4.1
boto3==1.11.16
botocore==1.14.16
ca-certificates==2020.1.1
cachetools==4.0.0
```

Comment: Instead of altering the file, you can use `awk NR!=1 '...'` to skip the first line. And in case OP isn't in an interactive shell, using `conda run -n myenv python -m pip install -r new_requirements.txt` will be more robust